# How do i get this code to copy only the rows that match my object matching criteria? currently if copies every row

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, google-apps-script

Currently this code copies every row and not the ones that match my criteria
I had some issues getting it to loop.  Hence the  loggers.
I'm quite new to this.

```
  function searchAnotherSheetAndReturnRows(){
Logger.clear()
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1dX5MMLXGsG_S_KzRhOcquOp00VhzRBSlTCkyw'); // tss = target spreadsheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // ts = target sheet
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ImDswr6ADS7t4HKIFHpntykN2LS7Mmd-cls34'); // sss = source spreadsheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Page1'); // ss = source sheet
 var tslast_row = ts.getLastRow();

var i=0;
Logger.log(i)

for (var i = 1; i < tslast_row; i++) {
Logger.log(i)

Logger.log(tslast_row);
 var ssSearch1 = ss.getRange(2,1).getValue();
     Logger.log(ssSearch1); 
 var tsSearch1 = ts.getRange(i,1).getValue();
     Logger.log(tsSearch1);

if (ssSearch1 == tsSearch1); {


     var  tsSearch1Range = ts.getRange(i,1,1,7);
     Logger.log(tsSearch1Range);
     var range2Copy = tsSearch1Range.getValues();//  Copies data from root sheet
     Logger.log(range2Copy);
     var last_row = ss.getLastRow();
     Logger.log(last_row);
     var last_row = last_row+1;
     Logger.log(last_row);
     ss.getRange(last_row,1,1,7).setValues(range2Copy);// Adds  root sheet data to target


}
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really hard to figure out what you're trying to do.  So here's an example that will hopefully help you a little.  The job of this function is to copy rows in the AlaskanWilderness that contain GOLD to MyPocket. (Names of Sheets)

```
function moveGoldFromAlaskanWildernessToMyPocket() {
  var tss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('id'); 
  var ts=tss.getSheetByName('MyPocket');
  var sss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('id');
  var ss=sss.getSheetByName('AlaskanWildernes');
  var sr=ss.getDataRange()
  var sd=sr.getValues();
  var criteria='GOLD';
  for (var i=1;i<sd.length;i++) {//skip header
    for(var j=0;j<sd[i].length;i++) {
      if (sd[i][j]=='GOLD'); {
        ss.appendRow(sd[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[sheet.appendRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))

[range.getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())

Comment: Apologies for my confusing code.  I appreciate your input.  it seems that the line  ```  for(var j=0;j<sd[i].length;i++) { ```   give this warning " TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 72, file "Code")"    is that a problem with my data?

Comment: It's not meant to be a drop in replacement.  I couldn't figure what you were trying to accomplish, but it was clear to me that you didn't have a grasp on the fundamentals of dealing with ranges and values so I was just offering up a facsimile example that you could learn from to accomplish the goal close described in your title.

Comment: Yep, I didn’t expect it to be but it seems that what you are trying to accomplish with your code is similar to what I’m trying to do. I thought I would drop in my values to see how it behaves.  I am coming from a spreadsheet background and I’m sure that colors my view of the coding world.   I can read what your code is trying to do but it will not execute past that particular line. Apologies for my inexperience